# Cursor jumps from input to input when .reportValidity() is being assessed as a variable

Tags: javascript, html, input, checkvalidity

I am checking the validity of five unique inputs to prevent form submission when invalid inputs remain.

```
sE.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  if (
    Number.isNaN(e.target.valueAsNumber) ||
    sE.valueAsNumber >= Number(sE.max) ||
    sE.valueAsNumber <= Number(sE.min)
  ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    calcButton.disabled = true;
  } else {
    calcButton.disabled = false;
  }
```

This does appear to work to prevent the calculation button from being enabled, but only when the input (ie `sE`) is being looked at. This doesn't look at all the other inputs.

So I thought it would be better to try this:

```
sE.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  let reportS = sE.reportValidity();
  let reportU = uE.reportValidity();
  let reportV = vE.reportValidity();
  let reportA = aE.reportValidity();
  let reportT = tE.reportValidity();
  console.log(reportS, reportU, reportV, reportA, reportT);
  if (
    Number.isNaN(e.target.valueAsNumber) ||
    sE.valueAsNumber >= Number(sE.max) ||
    sE.valueAsNumber <= Number(sE.min)
  ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    calcButton.disabled = true;
  } else {
    calcButton.disabled = false;
  }
});
```

This gives me the appropriate true/false relationship between all five inputs. But, when you click on one of the inputs on the HTML form and enter a number, the cursor then jumps to the last selected input. This makes input impossible.

When I removed the `let` statements and put them outside of the function they do not call the correct true/false relationship as they aren't updated as each input has new data added. However, when the `let` statements are outside of the function, even though they do not accurately reflect the true/false relationship, the cursor does not jump from input to input.

I am very much a beginner so I am not sure what to look for when it comes to troubleshooting this strange phenomenon.

I made a JSBin for this https://jsbin.com/gowulec/edit?html,js,output

When you click all three checkboxes and then try to add data into the input.

Comment: your title mentions `.checkValidity()` your code has `.reportValidity()` - and there's no code to explain what either code actually even is

Comment: I just added a JSBin and I will edit (I was testing the difference between check and report). Apologies, that was sloppy.

Comment: oh, I see what `.checkValidity` and `.reportValidity` are now ... seems they focus on invalid elements ..

Comment: Yeah, so my plan was to check for invalid inputs and prevent the submit button from being pushed.

Comment: to be honest, all the examples I've seen don't do it on every keystroke on every input like you do

Comment: What would you suggest? What if someone copies and pastes a number in the input?

Comment: @PaulDavis Usually you wait until they submit the form before checking. Otherwise it makes it hard to edit, since it might be invalid until you finish typing.

Comment: @Barmar - yeah, this is a special case scenario though. This is because a 5 point calculation is made and certain outcomes can't occur so I don't want a calculation to occur until the inputs are deemed valid. So for functionality, I am locking the submit button until valid.

Comment: @Barmar were you able to see the JSBin https://jsbin.com/gowulec/edit?html,js,output - is there anything obvious that is making this behaviour of the cursor jumping?

Comment: Haven't looked yet, but [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) is preferable to jsbin or jsfiddle.